# American Marketing Association Reference style

Tags: bibtex

I searched the www for hours to find someone who created a BibTeX or LaTeX file that looks like the rules of the American Marketing Association (below an example):

> Wensley, Robin (1981), "Strategic
>   Marketing": Betas, Boxes or Basics,"
>   *Journal of Marketing,* 45 (Summer), 173-82.

or another example:

> Bettmann, James R. and Mita Sujan
>   (1987), "Marketing in
>   Technology-Intensive Markets",
>   *Journal of Marketing*, 63 (Special Issue), 78-91

Has anyone experiences or solutions how to create this?

Comment: Looks like an author-year style without any major quirks. Consider to use biblatex.

Comment: looks quite good... but how do I cite it right in the text that it appears like (Hauser 2006)? Right now the author and year is in bold...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried makebst in the [custom-bib package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/)? The readme at the link explains it, but basically, you run latex on the `makebst.tex` file and answer the prompts to generate a `.bst` file for your bibliographic style.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like an author-year style without any major quirks. Consider to use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex).